# Kivy - Binding a Label's Text to a Variable in Another Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to get the label’s text in “EventWindow” to update when the variable “current_text” in the Event class in “scripts/events.py”.  I realize that the answer may lie in binding “current_text” to “ct”, but that just results in “AttributeError: class Event has no attribute ‘bind’”. If I am barking up the wrong tree with this solution, I would be very receptive of another method.

Below are the relevant code snippets, but the full project is available at: https://github.com/DinkWerks

## main.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.app import App
# Utility Imports
import yaml
# Game Imports
from scripts.events import Event

# File Loads
loc_file = file('data/location.yml')
loc_dat = yaml.load(loc_file)

# Bind Classes
event = Event()

class EventWindow(BoxLayout):
    ct = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EventWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ct = event.current_text
        # Error occurs below. Comment out too see semi-functional app.
        Event.bind(current_text=self.setter('ct'))
```

## scripts/events.py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...
from player import Player
from enemy import Enemy


class Event(Player):
    open_events = file('data/event.yml', 'r')
    event_file = yaml.load(open_events)
    current_text = StringProperty('1234')

    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)
        self.events = Event.event_file
        self.selection = ''
        self.current_text = '1234'

def event_name(self):
    ...

def event_selector(self, eid):
    ...

def parse(self):
    driver = 1
    variables = ('Name', 'Is_Person', 'Level', 'Gold')
    poss_commands = ("[Next Slide]", "[Query]", "[Terminate]", "[Combat]")

    while driver >= 0:
        text = self.events[self.selection][driver]
        lexer = shlex(text)
        lexer.quotes = '/'

        output = ''
        command = ''
        for token in lexer:
            if token in variables:
                output += str(eval('Player.' + token))
            elif token.replace('/', '') in poss_commands:
                command += token.replace('/', '')
            else:
                output += token.replace('/', '')
        self.current_text = output
        driver += self.controller(command)
    self.modifier()

def modifier(self):
    ...

def controller(self, cmd):
    ...
```

## text.kv

```
<EventWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos: 100,100
        size_hint: .4,.7
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            source: 'maps/map.jpg'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        ScrollView:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [.2,.2,.2,.8]
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Label:
                id: text_area
                text: root.ct
                padding: 15,10
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
<Foo>:
    id: bl
    popup: popup.__self__
    header: header
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            ...
        FloatLayout:
            id: mapspace
            canvas:
                ...
            EventWindow:
                id: event
    Popup:
        ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Event` does not have the methods and mechanisms implemented to deal with events as used by kivy. Try to make it a subclass of [`EventDispatcher`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html), unless your `Player` class does strange things it should just work.

Comment: This works perfectly, and makes absolute sense. I would gladly register this as the correct answer if you wished to resubmit it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `Event` is derived from `Player`, which itself is an [old style class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass). Importantly, neither implement methods necessary for event management (e.g. `fbind`; for a stub class defining an interface see [`Observable`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.Observable)). Most likely it is enough to make `Event` or `Player` a subclass of [`EventDispatcher`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher) to be able to create and bind to events kivy-style.